# include terminating newline in middle mouse button paste

Tags: bash, mouse, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-22.04

Ubuntu 22's `gnome-terminal` lets you click-drag a selection including a terminating newline (say, a command to run).  But when you paste it back into the shell by clicking the middle mouse button, the newline is omitted.  The command just sits there, waiting for you to hit enter.  This behavior wasn't in Ubuntu 18, nor in any earlier X11 implementation that I know of.

(If you paste into, say, `vi`, the newline is included.  So the copying was intact.  What's corrupted is the pasting.)

**How can I restore the old behavior?**  One click, instead of a click plus a keystroke.

- I got thoroughly lost in `gsettings`.
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/blob/master/src/org.gnome.Terminal.gschema.xml mentions nothing about the mouse.
- "Bracketed paste" (only on macOS iTerm?) might mean pasting the newline *but still* having to hit enter.
- This is in the [awesomewm](https://awesomewm.org/) window manager and the `bash` shell, if that matters.
- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. GNOME Terminal 3.44.0 using VTE 0.68.0 +BIDI +GNUTLS +ICU +SYSTEMD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `~/.bashrc` add the line `bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste off'`.
The new behavior, bracketed paste on by default, started in bash 5.1.